# why if statement not working as expected with multiple conditions when calling crystal reports asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am printing result report in medical laboratory system , and i have IF statement with multiple conditions with && and || , then i call crystal report depending on that condition and I am using stored procedure and passing parameters when run the report. 
IF statement not working and not passing parameters to the report .
I am using this code when click print link and in page load :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {


                TXTORDERID.Text = Request.QueryString["order_id"].ToString();
                TXTDEPTID.Text = Request.QueryString["DEPT ID"].ToString();

    if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["custid"]) > 1 && Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 1 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 2 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 3 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 4 )
                        {
                            paramField.Name = "@ORDER_ID";
                            paramDiscreteValue.Value = TXTORDERID.Text.ToString();
                            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                            paramFields.Add(paramField);

                            paramField = new ParameterField(); 
                            paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue(); 
                            paramField.Name = "@deptid";
                            paramDiscreteValue1.Value = TXTDEPTID.Text.ToString();
                            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue1);
                            paramFields.Add(paramField);

                            CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
                            CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
                            CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
                            reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/RPT/RPT_RESULTS.rpt"));
                            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
}
```

now when i use the IF statement like this code its not passing the parameters direct to the report and ask for report parameters order_id and dept_id

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["custid"]) > 1 && Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 1 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 2 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 3 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 4 )
```

and when i use IF statement like this code with () after && its not ask for parameter and run empty report

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["custid"]) > 1 && (Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 1 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 2 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 3 || Convert.ToInt32(TXTDEPTID.Text) == 4) )
```

how to update IF statement to run the report without ask for report parameter value @order_id and @deptid ?

[image]

Comment: I think there is something not match your IF statement criteria , check the custid session variable value Convert.ToInt32(Session["custid"]) > 1 .

Comment: Hi Abdullah, does the post below answer your original question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its an old post, but if it's of some help to somebody else

*Essentially your 2 if statements summarizes as below*

- `if( boolean1 &&  boolean2 || boolean3 || boolean4 || boolean5)`
  The expression evaluates boolean1 and boolean2 if true then checks the remaining
- `if(boolean1 && (boolean2 || boolean3 || boolean4 || boolean5))`
  The expression evaulates boolean1 && the result of boolean in the paranthesis

You can read about `Conditional logical operators` and its `short-circuit` behavior
 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-)